# How to update the UI of a VC from an outside function in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, uiviewcontroller, protocols

My problem is the following:

I have a `URLSession` service that stores data in Core Data on a regular base. Next to that, I have a Core Data service that retrieves data every 5 seconds for certain items that need to be updated on the UI.

I have defined a protocol in the Core Data service

```
protocol sendDataToMap : class {
    func updateMapLabels(tag : Int, value : String)
}
```

and I have added these class to the VC of the UI

in the Core Data service I now call the `updateMapLabels()` every 5 seconds
so that the actual function in the VC can update the UI.

```
  sendDataToMap.updateMapLabels(tag : tag, value : record.dataValue)
```

However the build fails and complains at the above line:

> extra argument 'value' in the call

Anybody knows what goes wrong here?

Comment: What class is the protocol overwriting?

Comment: @Leon: Not sure what you mean. The protocol is meant to connect the class to the viewController for channeling the (tag, value) info.

Comment: Use NSNotification to update the UI,I believe this will be better than protocol for your situation.